# Can not set browser cookie with response headers

Tags: session, next.js, cookies, passport.js

I'm currently utilizing Node.js Express along with PassportJS (local strategy) and Next JS 13 . However, I'm encountering an issue where I'm receiving a response header with a 'Set-Cookie' attribute. The browser is indicating that it cannot be set due to domain conflicts, which, to my understanding, is not accurate. The domain attribute is consistent with the next JS domain.

[image]

I'm perplexed by this situation because when I attempt to set the cookie manually from the console, it sets successfully as the following

`document.cookie='connect.sid=s%3AH0UQTiqfkhyxnjufv0dQVI65c3pNfYhK.w%2FagwDesw6Nd5M3iRwbnTOQPSOiMpz2oC5Is6DLln7g; Domain=.next-auth-app-six-delta.vercel.app; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 08 Mar 2024 22:37:03 GMT; Secure; SameSite=None'`

Backend URL is :  `https://nanoauth.onrender.com/`
Front End URl is : `https://next-auth-app-six-delta.vercel.app/`

and this is my cors and session config  in the backend

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: "https://next-auth-app-six-delta.vercel.app",
    credentials: true, // Allow credentials (cookies) to be sent with requests
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type",
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    preflightContinue: false,
    maxAge: 3600
}))
//Middleware
app.use(session({
    proxy: true,
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false ,
    saveUninitialized: true ,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 7 days
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
        domain: ".next-auth-app-six-delta.vercel.app"
    }
}))
```

I am expecting that the response heders set the cookie in browser but it don't